# unterminated quoted string at or near

Tags: php, postgresql

I have the below SQL for postgresql database. I use it in PHP code. the below statement cause the error:

```
$name = "test#123";
$query = "SELECT * FROM \"Table_name\" WHERE \"Name\" = '" . $name . "'";
$result = pg_query($query)  or die('Query failed: 2.12 ' . pg_last_error());
```

if the statement without character `#` it work fine. but with the charater `#` the error encountred (unterminated quoted string at or near) . how Can i solve it ?!

Comment: What does your PHP look like? `#` without being in a string is a comment in most SQL languages, I presume PG as well. Sounds like a quote may be off in PHP.

Comment: I don't think the double-quotes are valid, maybe backticks or nothing.

Comment: I edited my queation

Comment: @AbraCadaver Double-quotes are fine in Postgresql and Oracle as name qualifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is fine, however `#` is legacy line comment symbol in PHP. Your query text gets truncated before it hence the unterminated quoted string. Try to escape it with a backslash.

```sql
SELECT * FROM "Table_name" WHERE "Name" = 'test\#123'
```

Well, not the case. Actually PHP code needs a touch - escape the double quotes.

```php
$name = "test#123";
$query = "SELECT * FROM \"Table_name\" WHERE \"Name\" = '" . $name . "';";
$result = pg_query($query)  or die('Query failed: 2.12 ' . pg_last_error());
```

**Please note** that the code above is SQL injection prone. Consider using PDO and a prepared statement. Example:

```php
$name = "test#123";
$sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM "Table_name" WHERE "Name" = :name;';
$db = new PDO(<your PDO connection string here>);
$st = $db -> prepare ($sql_query);
$result = $st -> execute([':name' => $name]) -> fetchAll();
```

Comment: honestly it look like what you wrote above :)

Comment: I'm grateful for suggestion.